# Не запускается проект с использованием Mono в Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: visual-studio, mac, mono, rider

На `MacBook pro 13 m1` не удается запускать учебные программы с использованием `Mono` ни в `Visual Studio for Mac`, ни в `Rider`.

Программы полностью рабочие, без проблем запускаются на `Windows 11` на `ASUS'е` товарища в `Visual Studio`.
[image: Приложение «mono-sgen64» неожиданно завершило работу.]

Answer (score 0):

Качайте под ARM64, у вас версия для Интеловских машин